# saving a value from a document snapshot from firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

in the following code i want to save the String data that i get from firestore inside the .then() method into another variable. but once its outside the method i lose the value.

```
String memberName = '';

    member.user.get().then(
      (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          memberName = documentSnapshot.get('Full_Name');
          print(memberName) //'John Smith'
        }
      },
    );

print(memberName) //''
```

posting all the code for reference.

```
 Widget buildGroupMemberTile(GroupMember member, bool loggedUserIsAdmin) {
    final memberDoc = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('groups')
        .doc(widget.group.id)
        .collection("members")
        .doc(member.email);
    print(getMemberName(member));

String memberName = '';

    member.user.get().then(
      (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          memberName = documentSnapshot.get('Full_Name');
          print(memberName) //'John Smith'
        }
      },
    );

print(memberName) //''

    return ListTile(
        onTap: (() {
          if (loggedUserIsAdmin) {
            if (member.role == 'admin') {
              memberDoc.update({'role': 'member'});
            } else if (member.role == 'member') {
              memberDoc.update({'role': 'admin'});
            }
          }
        }),
        title: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
            child: Container(
              width: 450,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 65, 61, 82),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 20, 40, 20),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      memberName,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        color: ThemeColors.whiteTextColor,
                        fontSize: FontSize.large,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Im guessing that I'm referencing `documentSnapshot.get('Full_Name')` and not copying its the value to `memberName`. How can i keep the value?

Comment: I know i can get the value from a Future/Stream builder but I'm trying to avoid using those because i feel there's a simpler way without making another call to the Firestore.

Comment: You can access the data like this:  documentSnapshot['Full_Name']

Comment: Thank you that makes the code a little nicer, but it doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1):

try to get it like this without the `then`, and call the `data()` first to get the `Map<String, dynamic>` of the docuemnt:

```
 DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =  await member.user.get();
   if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
      memberName = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["Full_Name"];
      print(memberName);
    }
```

Note: you need to mark the method where this is implemented to `Future` with `async` keyword

Comment: thank you but this doesn't work for me, as i need it implemented into a widget. ill edit the question to contain all the code. my bad

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to put the entire `member.user.get()` call into a `async` future method & place an `await` keyword just before the call.

Then you need to use a `FutureBuilder` around the widget that will be displaying the name to ensure the name has a value before it is rendered.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).